# Unexpected possible undefined behaviour when assigning uninitialised memory as a C++ container

Tags: c++, containers, variable-assignment

If you compile this

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
using std::vector;

int main(){
    vector<int> v0,*v1;
    v1=(vector<int>*)malloc(sizeof(vector<int>)); //cf v1=new vector<int>;
    v1[0]=v0;
    while(1);
}
```

using

```
g++ -o UB-assignment UB-assignment.cpp -g -Wall
```

then there will be no compiler warnings and it will run fine, but if you run it under Valgrind,

```
valgrind --track-origins=yes UB-assignment
```

it will flag up two undefined behaviour warnings:

```
==12668== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==12668==    at 0x400A62: std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::operator=(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&) (vector.tcc:185)
==12668==    by 0x400962: main (UB-assignment.cpp:11)
==12668==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==12668==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==12668==    by 0x40094B: main (UB-assignment.cpp:10)
==12668== 
==12668== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==12668==    at 0x400B3A: std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::operator=(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&) (vector.tcc:197)
==12668==    by 0x400962: main (UB-assignment.cpp:11)
==12668==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==12668==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==12668==    by 0x40094B: main (UB-assignment.cpp:10)
```

Why would this happen? I realise I can easily avoid the problem by not using malloc, but I am looking to understand what is happening here. I assume that the problem is nothing to do with destructing uninitialised memory, because the infinite loop prevents it ever going out of scope.

(This happens with other containers. 'vector' is just an example.)

Comment: You are using the memory as if it contained a `vector<int>` when in fact it does not contain a `vector<int>`  (because you have not issued any code which begins the lifetime of a vector).  You just malloc'd some bytes and pretend a vector magically appears in that space.

Comment: I didn't _use_ the malloced space as a vector. I only assigned to it. I want to understand why the assignment A=B is trying to use A as an object.

Comment: `A=B` means `A.operator=(B)` which is a function call. The assignment operator will do things such as delete pointer to old memory containing the vector contents, etc.

Comment: @PetuniaBowl, The compiler is letting you run with scissors.  Valgrind is smart enough to know you missed something, the constructor, and is telling you, "You could poke your eye out."

Comment: @M.M It won't try to free the old memory until the vector goes out of scope, which it doesn't here. (It can't because there might be another reference to it, and C++ doesn't use garbage collection.)

Comment: @PetuniaBowl um no.. e.g. the assignment operator could be written `{ delete this->p;  this->p = new int[other.size]; ..... }` But `this->p` will be garbage to start with so you try to delete a wild pointer.

Comment: @PetuniaBowl You're on a complety wrong track. `malloc()` doesn't call any constructors, if you want to call constructors use `new` or better use some [smart pointer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory).

Comment: "there might be another reference to it" - if an object dies while there are references to it then those references become invalid (using them causes undefined behaviour).  You sound like you're describing Java or C# where an object lives until there are no more references to it.  This has nothing to do with this particular question though, since there never was an object in the space to begin with

Comment: `v1[0]` is a method call on `std::vector`. This calls `std::vector::operator[]()` which assumes the object underneath it has been correclty constructed using `std::vector::vector()` which it has not. Thus it is not surprizing the valgrind is indicating an error. The method `std::vector::operator[]()` is following an uninitialized pointer to a memory location that does not exist.

Comment: @M.M Thanks. I think I was confused between specified behaviour and behaviour in practice. You are right that references to LHS of a vector assignment become invalid after the assignment.

In practice (on the implementation I'm using, and I think widely), the internal array used by the LHS vector in an assignment is not freed, which is the reason for the pattern vector<int>().swap(a); when you really want to free the memory used by a vector that isn't about to go out of scope. Obviously to rely on this would be UB, but it does mean that operator= doesn't need to access the LHS's array.

Comment: Thank you @Loki Astari, but I don't think it's using std::vector::operator[](). v1 is not a vector, but a pointer to a vector, or did I misunderstand?

Comment: Anyway, what people have said is helpful, so thank you. Having read some more, I'm less surprised by this behaviour. A possible specific answer as to why this copy constructor may want to read from the LHS might be that the assignment may make use of the LHS's allocator.

Comment: @PetuniaBowl regardless of the implementation details, it's undefined behaviour to call a non-static member function on an "object" which was not actually constructed.

Comment: "why this copy constructor may want to read from the LHS " - the copy-constructor doesn't, but the assignment operator does. If you used a copy-constructor instead then everything is fine.

Comment: @PetuniaBowl: OK. Take my last comment and replace `std::vector::operator[]()` with `std::vector::operator=()` and all the rest applies. The point is you are suing a method on an object that is completely undefined. The precondition of a method is that there is a valid object, to have a valid object the constructor must run.

Comment: @M.M Sorry, quite right, I meant assignment operator not copy constructor.

To all: I realise that it's wrong to do this and the "problem" could easily be avoided. (I said so in my original question.) I also know that it is undefined behaviour in terms of the C++ spec., but that doesn't force an implementation to behave in an undefined way. I was curious as to why an implementation of operator= would actually want to behave in an undefined way in this situation, i.e. was curious as to what part of operator= is making a decision based on the LHS that is about the be overwritten.

Comment: @PetuniaBowl is your curiosity satisfied now? I can convert my comments into an answer if so.

Comment: @M.M Well... not completely satisfied since I wanted to know what operator= was doing that made it behave like that, but you've been very helpful which I appreciate, and you've more-or-less convinced me that my question isn't important, which is a kind of answer, so I'd be happy to accept your comments.

Comment: @PetuniaBowl I think my comment above starting "um no..." which shows  what operator= could be doing explains the rationale behind the situation

Comment: @M.M As mentioned, it's definitely not doing delete this->p on my implementation (g++) or, I think, on most implementations, so the reason is something else. Possibly it's trying to reuse the allocator, or something. But I think you basically explained that it's not interesting to look for the precise reason, and I've learnt several things on the side from what you said, so I'm happy really!

Comment: @PetuniaBowl sooner or later, the old `this->p` will be deallocated. Perhaps it goes via a swap, or re-used for a while, but ultimately that memory address must be freed. If it were not then this would be a memory leak for correctly-constructed vectors, but we know that they do not have memory leaks.

Comment: @M.M sure, but the deallocation happens (in practice, if not by spec) when the vector goes out of scope, which is after the UB, so it's not deallocation that's causing the UB here.

Comment: @PetuniaBowl maybe you could step in with a debugger or inspect assembly output to see exactly what your implementation is doing.

Answer (score 4):

Never use `malloc` with any C++ classes or standard library containers. `malloc` just allocates a chunk of bytes in memory. Nothing more. `std::vector` has a vital constructor that must be evoked, otherwise is garbage.

Your code is syntactically correct, thus it compiles. However, the malloced vector is a mush of uninitialized values, because the vector's constructor wasn't evoked.

Valgrind is warning you that in the statement:

```
v1[0]=v0;
```

You're "playing" with uninitialized values (i.e., the uninitialized guts of the vector). Something that causes UB.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I don't think it answers my question. Obviously malloced memory contains garbage. I want to know what is going on that tries to make use of the LHS of the assignment.

By comparison, this would work with POD. If int*a pointed to sizeof(int) bytes of unallocated memory, and int b defined a genuine int, then a[0]=b would be an unproblematic assignment. What extra structure is there that makes this a problem with vectors?

I'm not looking to use this (as explained in the question), but to understand it.

Comment: Valgrind is seeing the assignment, and checking the thing assigned to the LHS.  Where did it come from?  Was it initialized properly?  And Valgrind sees that it never was.  Pretty smart, that utility.  It recognizes that a class needs more (a constructor) than a scalar, such as an int.

Comment: @donjuedo Are you sure? Valgrind isn't some kind of style-checker. It is a virtual machine that runs your program. Here it is detecting actual undefined behaviour in the std library, and I would like to know why this occurs.

Comment: Valgrind can easily keep track of memory allocations, and know if something came from malloc (and friends) or not.  I don't know which technique it uses, but in the old days, the memory debuggers would patch new, or malloc, or both.  They can add metadata in front of the returned pointer, as well as other tricks.